# How to delete characters after a "." (dot) in the first column?

Tags: columns, delete

I want to delete characters after "." in the first column of my file, which looks like this:

```
location    LR  alpha
14884399.000000 0.471193    3.029710e+01
14904434.024291 0.440564    1.300841e-05
14924469.048583 0.356903    1.329721e-05
```

I want it to look like this:

```
location    LR  alpha
14884399    0.471193    3.029710e+01
14904434    0.440564    1.300841e-05
14924469    0.356903    1.329721e-05
```

I have tried these 2, they work but delete the second and the third columns:

````
echo ${input_var} | sed 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g' chr22.E.Asia.clrout

cat chr22.E.Asia.clrout | sed chr22.E.Asia.clrout col=1 's/\.[^ ]*/ /g' > new_chr22.E.Asia.clrout```
````

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome, that's because you are using the `g` greedy command.

Comment: Thank you for the fast feedback! What should I use instead of g?

Comment: Nothing, without it, the substitutin will be performed in the first match only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment seem's that you have resolved, however, here another couple of ways :

```
sed -E 's/(^[[:digit:]]+)\.[[:digit:]]+([[:space:]]+)/\1\2/g' file
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk '{ sub(/\.[[:digit:]]+/, " ", $1) }1' file
```